# Handle the event "Excel is closing"

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I have a vb .net app which opens an Excel file and puts values in it. But if the user (who I have to assume is extremely dumb :) ), closes the workbook, next time my app will try to put a value to the file, it will show an error since there is no excel file open.

How can I either prevent excel from being closed, or disable the buttons when excel is closed?

I'm working with Excel 2003 on Windows 7

EDIT: Here is the code to open Excel

```
Private Sub Open_button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Open_button.Click


    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls"
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    filePath = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    If System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) Then
        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oExcel.Visible = True
        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(filePath)


        oSheet = oBook.WorkSheets(1)
        oExcel.Sheets(1).Select()
        oExcel.ScreenUpdating = True
        xlDown = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlDown
        xlUp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp
        Me.Activate()

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to open and modify the Excel file?  You don't have to automate Excel to modify an excel file - you can open it and modify it internally without needing to launch a visual instance of the application and control it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbookevents_event.beforeclose%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: J I need Excel to be visible to the user. I'll put the code on the question.
Hans this seems like what I need but I don't understand how to use it

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

You can add event handler to detect the close event and disable the button in the handler.
From https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/822750

```
Private EventDel_BeforeBookClose As Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler
```

Then after you have created the Excel objects

```
EventDel_BeforeBookClose = New Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler( _
        AddressOf BeforeBookClose)
AddHandler xlApp.WorkbookBeforeClose, EventDel_BeforeBookClose
```

And add a sub to handle the event

```
Private Sub BeforeBookClose(ByVal Wb As Excel.Workbook, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
```